# Merge variables in an array with all posibilities

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to get an array with three variables ("Branch", "Year" and "Mins") in which there are all possible options. I have tried:

```
Branch <- c("branch1", "branch2", "branch3")
Year <- c("y1", "y2", "y3")
Mins <- c(1:5)
bind_rows(Branch,Year,Mins)
```

I would like to get an array like this:

```
  Branch Year Mins
1 branch1   y1    1
2 branch1   y1    2
3 branch1   y1    3
4 branch1   y1    4
5 branch1   y1    5
6 branch1   y2    1
7 branch1   y2    2
8 branch1   y2    3
9 branch1   y2    4
```

...

Answer (score 1):

We could use `expand.grid`

```
expand.grid(Branch, Year, Mins)
```

Comment: It worked! I did not know about this function. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (but very similar) approach using `tidyr` (within `tidyverse`):

First we load your sample data:

```
# your sample data
Branch <- c("branch1", "branch2", "branch3")
Year <- c("y1", "y2", "y3")
Mins <- c(1:5)
```

First step is to make a `tibble`, in this example we turn the `Branch` vector into a single-column `tibble`:

```
library(tidyverse)

Branch %>% 
  as_tibble

# # A tibble: 3 x 1
# value  
# <chr>  
# 1 branch1
# 2 branch2
# 3 branch3
```

Then, we can use `tidyr::expand` to make a new column for your `Year` variables, and include all possible combinations of `Branch` and `Year`:

```
Branch %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  expand(value, Year)

# A tibble: 9 x 2
# value   Year 
# <chr>   <chr>
# 1 branch1 y1   
# 2 branch1 y2   
# 3 branch1 y3   
# 4 branch2 y1   
# 5 branch2 y2   
# 6 branch2 y3   
# 7 branch3 y1   
# 8 branch3 y2   
# 9 branch3 y3
```

Or, we can supply `expand` with both `Year` and `Mins`, to find all combinations of all three variables:

```
Branch %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  expand(value, Year, Mins)

# # A tibble: 45 x 3
# value   Year   Mins
# <chr>   <chr> <int>
# 1 branch1 y1        1
# 2 branch1 y1        2
# 3 branch1 y1        3
# 4 branch1 y1        4
# 5 branch1 y1        5
# 6 branch1 y2        1
# 7 branch1 y2        2
# 8 branch1 y2        3
# 9 branch1 y2        4
# 10 branch1 y2        5
# # ... with 35 more rows
```

Note the column with the `Branch` values is automatically called `'value'` by `as_tibble()`. You could use `dplyr::rename` to change it, or use `as_tibble_col()` and specify `column_name` instead of `as_tibble`:

```
Branch %>% 
  as_tibble_col(column_name = 'Branch') %>% 
  expand(Branch, Year, Mins)

# # A tibble: 45 x 3
# Branch  Year   Mins
# <chr>   <chr> <int>
# 1 branch1 y1        1
# 2 branch1 y1        2
# 3 branch1 y1        3
# 4 branch1 y1        4
# 5 branch1 y1        5
# 6 branch1 y2        1
# 7 branch1 y2        2
# 8 branch1 y2        3
# 9 branch1 y2        4
# 10 branch1 y2        5
# # ... with 35 more rows
```